# New company asking for the resignation letter submitted to current company

Tags: hiring-process, resignation

I have signed a contract with a Singapore IT company (through an hiring agent company). They need me to start work there ASAP. So I gave my resignation to my current company a few days ago.

But today the hiring agent from the new company called me and asked for a copy of my resignation letter. I refused to give it. But they are saying this is their procedure.

1. Is this normal?
2. I thought the resignation letter is confidential. Is it not?
3. Do they have the right to request my resignation letter and do I need to submit it?

Comment: Can't really comment on what counts as normal in Singapore, but for other locales: 1) No, your resignation letter is generally considered company confidential; 2) Yes, exactly that; 3) They can ask for whatever they want (within reason); 4) No, but nothing guarantees that they won't retaliate if you do not.

Comment: Maybe theres's confusion about your resignation letter and a written statement from the company that you have been released. I have seen questions on this site indicating that in certian countries you need proof of having terminated job X as a condition of starting job Y. And even if there's no confusion, you can ask if that proof termination will do.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Because resignation letter is something between me and my current company. It doesn't  have any relationship with the new company. And this is the first time i faced such request. So i became `OMG`

Comment: Still unclear why you care about this. "between me and my current company" doesn't make much sense as an excuse.

Comment: two things come in mind: when I am asked to breach confidentiality, I always remind people that if I do it, then they could never trust I would respect confidentiality with them; also, it may not be the company asking, but the recruitment service, anxious to see if they'll get their money

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping legality aside, what is the problem in sharing a copy of your resignation letter ? This can be one of the only ways the hiring manager can know that you have surely started your process of leaving the other company.

> Is this normal?

Based on other questions on this site I can almost see why its normal in Asian countries to do this. Although in my opinion it doesn't really make any sense as you could always pull back your resignation and it isn't really hard to fudge an already sent resignation email. 
So, although strange, I think this really could be the procedure your hiring manager follows and I don't think there is harm in sharing your resignation letter.

> I thought the resignation letter is confidential. Is it not?

I have never heard of a resignation *letter* being confidential. The process of resigning itself may be confidential but only for a couple of days. It isn't uncommon for a manager to announce to his team that X is leaving and the transition plans are in place etc.

> Do they have the right to request my resignation letter and do I need
>   to submit it?

That would depend on the law in Singapore. You don't need to submit it if you dont want to. I think you'd want to weigh in a lost opportunity versus sharing of the sacred resignation letter.